# Initialized readonly field is null, why?

Tags: c#

Can anyone please explain, why `private readonly Int32[] _array = new[] {8, 7, 5};` can be `null`?

In this example, it works, and `_array` is always not `null`. But in my corporate code I have a similar code and `_array` is always `null`. So I forced to declared it as static.

The Class is a partial Proxy Class from my WCF Contract.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace NullProblem
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myClass = new MyClass();

            // Null Exception in coperate code
            int first = myClass.First;
            // Works
            int firstStatic = myClass.FirstStatic;
        }
    }

    // My partial implemantation
    public partial class MyClass
    {
        private readonly Int32[] _array = new[] {8, 7, 5};
        private static readonly Int32[] _arrayStatic = new[] {8, 7, 5};

        public int First
        {
            get { return _array[0]; }
        }

        public int FirstStatic
        {
            get { return _arrayStatic[0]; }
        }
    }

    // from WebService Reference.cs
    public partial class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        // a lot of Stuff

        #region Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion
    }

}
```

Comment: It's not much use to show us code that works and say there's some other code that doesn't work. You need to give us a short but complete example which doesn't work.

Comment: If it works here and not in your code, it is quite obvious that there is something wrong with your code. Unless you post it I find it difficult to provide any help.

Comment: Works as intended in my LINQPad.

Comment: Sorry, I can't post corporate code here. It was more a question like is this even possible?

Comment: @MartinSeidensticker Well, it looks like the little information you provided was enough for getting you an answer.

Comment: At this very moment we discuss this answer in our office.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

WCF does not run the constructor (which includes the field initializer), so any objects created by WCF will have that null. You can use a serialization callback to initialize any other fields you need. In particular, `[OnDeserializing]`:

```
[OnDeserializing]
private void InitFields(StreamingContext context)
{
    if(_array == null) _array = new[] {8, 7, 5};
}
```

Comment: Can readonly fields be assigned outside of a constructor like this?

Comment: @Louis not without cheating, no. The "readlonly" would have to be removed

Comment: cheating means reflection? Or is there some special attribute that can be used?

Answer (score 3):

I recently ran into this issue too. I had an non-static class with static readonly variables, too. They always appeared `null`. **I think it's a bug**.

**Fix it by adding a static constructor to the class:**

```
public class myClass {
    private static readonly String MYVARIABLE = "this is not null";

    // Add static constructor
    static myClass() {
       // No need to add anything here
    }

    public myClass() {
       // Non-static constructor
    }

     public static void setString() {
       // Without defining the static constructor 'MYVARIABLE' would be null!
       String myString = MYVARIABLE;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd consider this guys answer before reporting any bugs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34259304/static-property-is-null-after-being-assigned/34260123?noredirect=1