# Static property is null after being assigned

Tags: c#, json.net

I have this code:

```
static class Global
{
    public static readonly IChannelsData Channels = new ChannelsData();
    public static readonly IMessagesData Messages = new MessagesData();
}
```

My understanding is that, because this class is static, it is impossible for `Global.Channels` or `Global.Messages` to be null now that they have been given an instance.

However, I try to access the property with

```
public class Channel : IComparable
{

    ...

    private SortedList<string, Message> _messages;

    [JsonConstructor]
    public Channel()
    {
        _messages = new SortedList<string, Message>();
    }

    [OnDeserialized]
    private void Init(StreamingContext context)
    {
        **Global.Channels.RegisterChannel(this);**
    }  

    ...

}
```

I get a `NullReferenceException` on `Global.Channels`, which I have confirmed in the immediate window. Further confusing me, I can hit the breakpoint at `new ChannelData()`, so I know the static member is being populated - successfully - at some point.

More context, comment request:

```
    private Hashtable _channels;

    public ChannelsData()
    {
        _channels = new Hashtable();

        foreach(Channel channel in SlackApi.ChannelList())
        {
            _channels.Add(channel.GetHashCode(), channel);
        }
    }
```

It feels like something similar to the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291428/initialized-readonly-field-is-null-why). However, in my situation I'm deserializing using JSON.NET and not WCF *and* the property in question is in a separate static class, not in the same class. I also can't use the workaround of a solution posted there.

Full stack trace:

> at Vert.Slack.Channel.Init(StreamingContext context) in C:\\Vert\Slack\Channel.cs:line 48

And error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: What's `OnDeserializedAttribute` and when will it be invoked?

Comment: It's invoked by JSON.NET when I attempt to deserialize a `Channel` json blob.

Comment: Wait, are you ***sure*** it's because `Channels` is null, and not an error inside `RegisterChannel`..?

Comment: Please post the full error + stack trace.

Comment: Solution *appears* to be here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291428/initialized-readonly-field-is-null-why

Comment: Yes, I can confirm in the immediate window that `Global.Channels` returns null

Comment: Full stack trace:    `at Vert.Slack.Channel.Init(StreamingContext context) in C:\<project path>\Vert\Slack\Channel.cs:line 48`

And error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: @Matt You can use [the edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34259304/edit) to add the stack trace in your original question.

Comment: @Rob this link is about instance fields, I don't think static fields have the same issue.

Comment: Or maybe you can use something like this: 
`private static IChannelsData _channels;
public static IChannelsData Channels
{
 get {return _channels ?? (_channels = new ChannelsData());}
 private set { _channels = value; }
}`

Comment: @DannyChen You're right - I missed that

Comment: @Matt You're not using `ThreadStatic` at all, are you?

Comment: @JleruOHeP - I don't recommend that, it's not thread-safe.  For thread-safe lazy initialization of a global singleton, see http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx.

Comment: What does `new ChannelsData()` do?  Is there any chance that it makes use of these two global singleons recursively?  The singleton value won't get set until after `new ChannelsData()` returns.

Comment: @Matt Is there *anything* written above your `Channels` definition? If there is, can you move `Channels` to the top of the class?

Comment: @Rob, no `ThreadStatic` anywhere, and I will update the question with more context from Channel, I am using `[JsonConstructor]`

Comment: @dbc, I'll update with context. Hopefully I can throw together a compilable sample that breaks tomorrow morning

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've been able to reproduce it with the following:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var m = Global.Messages;
    }
}
[Serializable]
public class Blah
{
    [OnDeserialized]
    public void DoSomething(StreamingContext context)
    {
        Global.Channels.DoIt(this);
    }
}
static class Global
{
    private static Blah _b = Deserialize();

    public static readonly IChannelsData Channels = new ChannelsData();
    public static readonly IMessagesData Messages = new MessagesData();

    public static Blah Deserialize()
    {
        var b = new Blah();
        b.DoSomething(default(StreamingContext));
        return b;
    }
}
```

Essentially, the order of execution is:

`var m = Global.Messages;` causes the static initializer to run for `Global`.

According to ECMA-334 regarding static field initialization:

> The static field variable initializers of a class declaration
>   correspond to a sequence of assignments that are executed in the
>   **textual order in which they appear in the class declaration**. If a
>   static constructor (§17.11) exists in the class, execution of the
>   static field initializers occurs immediately prior to executing that
>   static constructor. Otherwise, the static field initializers are
>   executed at an implementation-dependent time prior to the first use of
>   a static field of that class

**This is the root cause. See the comments for more context on the circular reference**

This essentially means that we're calling `Deserialize` and hitting `Global.Channels.DoIt(this);` before the initializer has a chance to finish setting up. As far as I'm aware, this is the *only* way a static field cannot be initialized before being used - after some testing, they are indeed created even when using run-time dispatches (`dynamic`), reflection *and* `GetUninitializedObject` (for the latter, initialization is done on the first method call, however)..

Though your code may be less obvious to diagnose (for example, if the chain is kicked off by another static class referencing). For example, this will cause the same issue but is not as immediately clear:

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       var t = Global.Channels;
   }
}
[Serializable]
public class Blah
{
   [OnDeserialized]
   public void DoSomething(StreamingContext context)
   {
       Global.Channels.DoIt();
   }
}

public interface IChannelsData { void DoIt(); }
class ChannelsData : IChannelsData
{
    public static Blah _b = Deserialize();
    public static Blah Deserialize()
    {
        var b = new Blah();
        b.DoSomething(default(StreamingContext));
        return b;
    }
    public void DoIt() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Done it");
    }
}

static class Global
{
    public static readonly IChannelsData Channels = new ChannelsData();
    public static readonly IMessagesData Messages = new MessagesData();  
}
```

So:

1. If you have anything else in `Globals` before those fields, you should investigate them (if they were left out for brevity). It may be simple as moving the `Channels` declaration to the top of the class.
2. Inspect `ChannelsData` for *any* static references, and follow those to the source.
3. Setting a breakpoint in `DoSomething` should give you a stack trace back to the static initializers. If it *doesn't*, try to replicate the issue by invoking `new Blah(default(StreamingContext))` where it would usually be deserialised.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what led you to "ECMA-334"?

Comment: @Matt Googling `C# Language Specification` gives takes you to http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm a few links down

Comment: 1. What I posted is the entire Globals.cs file, sans usings
2. So what you're getting at is that a separate **static** reference in `ChannelData`, say to `Utilitiy`, could be the root cause of this?
3. I'll give it a shot, thanks!

Comment: And, last question, how does your answer account for the fact that I can hit the breakpoint that populates the member (which I hit *before* ever attempting to reference it)

Comment: @Matt I would imagine you're hitting the breakpoint *but it's not actually assigning the variable yet*. This would be a symptom of #2 - in that we break on the line attempting to set the `ChannelsData`, but it first needs to go through the initialization process. As for it not being referenced, I'd need a closer look at your code to figure out why.

Comment: I really really want to understand what's happening here, and I keep thinking I do, but end up proving myself wrong. Could you further ELI5 the quote from the language specification? As I understand it, if I add a static constructor to Global, and then add `var init = Global.Channels` as the very first line in `main()`, it should initialize my static readonly variables, **BUT** I am still seeing the same error behavior. When I read the spec, it seems like this should also be a workaround for my problem (as I slowly refactor out my other static classes)

Comment: @Matt The text from the specification is essentially: The `static initializers` can run at any time, as long as it's *prior* to the first use of any of its fields. `static initializers` is the *group* of initializations of static fields. That is, you'd have a `static initializer` for the `Global` static class. Now, the initializers will initialize each field *in the order they're defined in the class*. That is, `Channels` will *always* be initialized before `Messages`. *Static constructors*'s only restriction is that *all fields* are initialized immediately before the constructor runs.

Comment: If you were to write `A.FieldA + B.FieldB` - there is *no* guarantee to the order that `FieldA` and `FieldB` are initialized. `FieldB` may be initialized before `FieldA`. The only requirement is that `FieldB` is initialized *before* it is being used. Putting a static constructor in `B`, however, changes that. Fields must be initialized **immediately before** the constructor, and therefore it's guaranteed that `FieldB` will never be initialized before `FieldA`.

Comment: I don't believe a static constructor could fix this issue - but I'd have to look at specific code to be sure. The entire issue is that static initializers are executed *synchronously* and somewhere in your code is a circular reference. In my example, the circular reference is `Global.Channels -> ChannelsData -> ChannelsData._b -> ChannelsData.Deserialize -> Blah.DoSomething -> Global.Channels`

Comment: Ohhhhh, *a circular reference*! :lightbulb: Thanks @Rob

Comment: @Matt No worries, mate - happy to help. Let me know if you're still stuck